# I have two models message and messageto and I am using message models attributes in the messageto form page how to validate those attributes

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

> I have two models message and messageto and I am using message models attributes in the messageto form page how to validate those attributes using ajax validation, I am new to YII.

I am using application.extensions.tokeninput.TokenInput to display the fields and I am unable to validate fields on these widgets. Thank you waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good understanding of [How-Yii-Ajax-Validation-Works](http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2010/12/yii.html) will help you a lot in using this feature & do some customization to it.

I am afraid i did not use **tokeninput extension** but regarding your two models ajax validation, the following *general plan* should work:

in your **View**, make sure you have:

```php
 $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
     'id'=>'some-id-for-your-form',
     'enableAjaxValidation'=>true //turn on ajax validation on the client side
));
```

Moreover in the **View**, any field with validation rule should have:

```php
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'some_attribute'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'some_attribute'); ?> // This is used to present validations error
```

and in your **Controller**, in create or update action before you load **View** inputs through `POST`, put the following lines:

```php
$messageModel = new Message;
$messageToModel = New MessageTo;

if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) 
{
  echo CActiveForm::validate( array( $messageModel,$messageToModel)); 
  Yii::app()->end(); 
}
/*
  The rest of your code goes here
*/
```

As for the extension you are using, if its auto-generate the View code, then you need to know how to configure it to put the needed `enableAjaxValidation => true` & the `$form->error($model,'some_attribute')` Parts.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Thank you, Nimir, Will check it.